# Identify if class is abstract with Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I've searched here I didn't find the answer here.

How can I know if class is a abstract class from a `ClassDeclarationSyntax`.

Here is my code:

```
public override void VisitClassDeclaration(ClassDeclarationSyntax node)
{
    var className = node.Identifier.Text;
    var namespaceName = (node.Parent as NamespaceDeclarationSyntax)?.Name.ToString();
    var isAbastract = ??????
}
```

Comment: Not an answer but a hint (since I've never used the Roslyn API): the Modifiers property should contain what you need

Comment: you are right. thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've found the answer. here is the code:

```
public override void VisitClassDeclaration(ClassDeclarationSyntax node)
{
    var className = node.Identifier.Text;
    var namespaceName = (node.Parent as NamespaceDeclarationSyntax)?.Name.ToString();

    var isAbstract = node.Modifiers.Any(x => x.IsKind(SyntaxKind.AbstractKeyword));
}
```