# How to know if class is abstract using roslyn framework

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I need to get all abstract class parsing the code by using Roslyn framework. Does someone already have a similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps you. simple like this:

`node.Modifiers.Any(x => x.IsKind(SyntaxKind.AbstractKeyword));`

node object is a ClassDeclarationSyntax.

[more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48833833/identify-if-class-is-abstract-with-roslyn/48834026#48834026)